# Node.js meteor.js fibers and loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, fibers

Okay i am learning fibers and i dont know how to implement the "waiting for end of the loop inside the fiber"

Now i have this code what works without problem.

```
        if (Meteor.isServer) {

        function checkIfIOwnThisItem(callback) {
           setTimeout(function() {
                callback("this callback");
            }, 500);
        }           

        var f = Fiber(function() {
            var fiber = Fiber.current;

            checkIfIOwnThisItem(function(str) {
                fiber.run(str);
            });

            str = Fiber.yield();
            console.log(str);
        });

        f.run();

    }
```

And i need to **replace** the **setTimeout** ...**FOR**...

```
        _.each(myBank.items,function(loopItem,key,list){
        if (loopItem.itemId == item.itemId) {
            ownItem = true;
            countOfOwnItemInBank = parseInt(loopItem.number);
        }
    });
```

**The whole point is to first check if i already OWN ITEM (own item is true) AND THEN i can do whatever hell i want but i need to be sure the ownItem is true**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are starting from some memories about fibers/threads in desktop programming and trying to map an exact equivalence.  I remember that world.  Don't think that way.  Fibers are more about not waiting around for an answer that could come any time.

I bet if you take smaller steps, think less, and just get some HTML/js to do what you want, then come back here when you hit a stopping block, you will make progress.

Ownership of items, for example, is commonly expressed by a field in a document, ownerid, matching current userid

Comment: hm... i want to ask is the _.each loop synchronous function? Can't i just put the code after it? btw: yes i could just check in mini mongo DB if i own that item but i think checking it in loop is better then accesing DB or am i wrong?

Comment: Rather than checking some object, if you use myCollection.find({ownerid: myid}) there is no doubt.  Also, if not drawing from a collection, look at http://underscorejs.org/#filter

Comment: and can you please answer the synchronous question from comment?

Comment: Short answer: yes.  Long answer: what do synchronous and asynchronous mean to you in terms of JS through the Meteor framework?  What problem led you to study fibers?

Comment: The doubt that my code what requires to know if ownItem is true(which is placed after each loop (where i figure it out) will run before the loop is finished and may have bad ownItem.

Comment: All js code you write is synchronous unless you call an explicitly async function with a callback.  The special thing about node.js is that they discovered doing so can make things really efficient.  But you usually get to choose between synchronous and asynchronous versions of the call you make, in meteor.  No accidental interrupt happens.

Comment: Okay so then my code is fine as it is? 

1. loop 2. after loop some code 3. i am fine

Comment: As a general idea, yes.  I'm not sure you ever need fibers, from everything you described. If so, you might accept an answer to help others know what worked.

Comment: i was probably too paranoid so i will stay with normal loop => then code. Without fibers. Thank you for your time and explanation. Marking as answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Fiber(function() {
  _.each(myBank.items,function(loopItem,key,list){
    if (loopItem.itemId == item.itemId) {
        ownItem = true;
        countOfOwnItemInBank = parseInt(loopItem.number);
    }
  }); 
}).run();
```

This code should work synchronous.

Comment: How I unerstand your are find a way to run you code synchronous outside of meteor methods and you want to use standard meteor environment. So this is an example how you get this.